# How to get correct links to source files in DevTools profiler in Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app, profiler

I've created a basic Create React App with TypeScript template

`npx create-react-app cra-test --template typescript`

I added just a simple `MyButton` component and passed a on click handler to it.
When I'm profiling it with Chrome DevTools links to the source in the profiler are incorrect and not working as if there where no source maps.

When I run `console.trace` in my onClick handler stack trace looks good.

**How can I get correct links to source files in the profiler tab working?**

Thanks!

[image: profiler with wrong source file links as if there was no source map]

[image: stack trace made with console.trace that shows proper source file names]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get this working you need to change webpack's setting

`devtool: 'eval-source-map'`

You can set it using `config-overrides.js` ([react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired)).

Probably there are some other source map types that will work but that one gives you the most detailed information.
More on source map types here

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

You can read about `devtool` setting here.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-source-maps

Comment: It's kinda nuts how far you have to go with CRA to have the most basic functionality - I thought it's whole purpose was to be easy to use out of the box?